# autofill this html field?

Tags: php, html, autofill

what would be the easiset way to autofill this field??

```
<input type="text" name="start_price" value="<?=$item_details['start_price'];?>" size="8"></td>
```

i need to keep the $item_details because it gets passed to some other code, but in some cases i want to autofill this as 0.00 to make it easier for me as i will be using 0.00 to list some auctions

i am editing a template that is being used by php to generate some code, so ideally i just want to make some changes to the templates without having to dive into the code itself

Comment: "...but in some cases..." What cases?

Comment: `if( some case ) { $autofill = '0.00'; } else { $autofill = $item_details[ 'start_price' ]; }` ... `value="<?php echo $autofill; ?>"`

Comment: @AlexLunix what i mean is that i need to keep the $item_Details[start_price] portion of it; so the shortest way to autofill this field is the best,

Comment: @Juhana That would make a great answer...

Comment: in other words how to autofill & pass 0.00 as the start_price

Comment: In your code, the part about $item_details is auto filling it...

Comment: so i cant change it in the template file? i have to change it in the function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this sounds like it might solve your problem:

```
<?php
  // Whatever logic determines a "special case" stores a boolean value 
  // into the variable $special_case
  $input_value = !$special_case ? $item_details['start_price'] : '0.00';
?>
<input type="text" name="start_price" value="<?php echo $input_value; ?>" size="8">
```